# Is there a way to make intellisense aware of instance members of an interface with dynamic indices?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am working on an angular project and I am using an interface to define a configuration for a module. The interface is designed to map names to objects and is fairly simple:

```
export interface NamedRoutes {
  [routeName: string]: NamedRoute;
}
```

When I create an instance of that interface, intellisense is not capable of resolving the members of the instance, when I use it. E.g.:

```
const routes: NamedRoutes {
  someRoute: {...}
};

const someRoute = routes. // no intellisense support here
```

As far as I know, the problem is, that when the compiler tries to backtrace the members, it sees that the indices are strings and therefore anything could be allowed, so it's not capable of suggesting the actually existing members.

When I omit the typing on the constant, intellisense is capable of suggesting the correct members. As far as I know, that's because the index names are then interpreted as symbols, not strings. The downside is, that users of my API would only get compiler support for errors, when they are passing the objects to my configuration method, which in case of our project can be on a completely different place than the object creation. In my opinion, that would be a very bad UX for the api.

I tried using different advanced types like `Record<string, NamedRoute>` and `<T extends string = string>` (for the index type).

I hope, I made clear, what my problem is and what I am trying to achieve. Is there a propper way of doing that?

P.S.: Using a type instead of an interface would be an option for our project, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can give users a helper function that they use to create `NamedRoutes` instances instead of letting them use a `NamedRoutes` annotation.  Something like this:

```
// I like examples that compile, so here's something random:
interface NamedRoute {
    whoKnows: string; 
}

export interface NamedRoutes {
    [routeName: string]: NamedRoute;
}

// helper function that just returns the input but makes sure it conforms to NamedRoutes    
const asNamedRoutes = <T extends NamedRoutes>(t: T) => t;

// correct use
const routes = asNamedRoutes({
    someRoute: { whoKnows: "blah" }
});

routes.someRoute // IntelliSense is here, yay!

// incorrect use so you still get early errors
const badRoutes = asNamedRoutes({
    badRoute: { nobodyKnows: "whoops " } // error!
    // type { nobodyKnows: string } is not assignable to NamedRoute
})
```

The `asNamedRoutes()` function is essentially the same as forcing people to pass the object to a method earlier than when they would normally do so, so that errors are surfaced earlier.  There are things you can do to make annotations of `NamedRoutes` less possible (making `NamedRoutes` a class with a private member would have this effect) but that's probably overkill.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your input! I was hoping to avoid helper functions but at least, this moves compiler errors to the creation line.